# setting up sharepoint 2010 development environment

Tags: sharepoint-2010, development-environment

We have sharepoint server 2010 with farm installation on VM.

We are 3 member in team and we want to work on development of sharepoint site, so what will be the requirement for development and how should we setup our development environment.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

start with a x64 os then follow these directions:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869(v=office.14).aspx